# Awk array syntax error

Tags: shell, awk

I am trying to use awk as some types of element counter as follows, but I got syntax error.

```
cat file | awk '{if($2>$3)A[$1]++}END{for(index in A){print index, A[index]}}'
```

Can someone help?

Here is the syntax error:

```
awk: {if($2>$3)A[$1]++}END{for(index in A){print index, A[index]}}
awk:                                 ^ syntax error
awk: {if($2>$3)A[$1]++}END{for(index in A){print index, A[index]}}
awk:                                                  ^ syntax error
awk: {if($2>$3)A[$1]++}END{for(index in A){print index, A[index]}}
awk:                                                           ^ syntax error
```

Thanks you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that `index` is a [reserved word](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xcu/awk.html#tag_000_000_108_016). Change it to something else. Perhaps `key`.

Answer (score 1):

#### Good Practices:

1. As Kevin pointed out, `index` is a reserved word. Try using a different `key` for your `array subscripts`.
2. **Useless use of `cat`**. `awk` can take `filename` as an input. Do something like this -

   `awk '{if($2>$3)A[$1]++}END{for(i in A){print i, A[i]}}' file`
3. If `$2>$3` is the only condition then you can shorten it to something like following -

   `awk '$2>$3{A[$1]++}END{for(i in A){print i, A[i]}}' file`